# How do I refresh the projects that I cannot see in the Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

So I copied a bunch of java projects into my eclipse-workspace, but I cannot refresh the projects because they cannot be seen in the Eclipse. Is there even a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to use File-Import-Existing_project into the workspace. (apply to each new project). Browse to the location where the .classpath and .project files locates in your project.